# Android: Changing layout based on phone specs

Tags: android

My app looks great on my phone, and on my AVD. On my co-dev's phone though, his screen is smaller and all the content isn't shown. Is there a way to detect how big the users screen is and adjust the layout from there? If so can someone link me a tutorial? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has two excellent articles on this subject:

- [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)
- [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Sam, on one of my activities in particular, I have a text view, an image view, and then another image view. The attributes are already set to "wrap_content" for height and width. I'm not sure how to make it fit on the small screen though. Should I go back into my images for ldpi and mdpi and scale the drawings down a bit?

Comment: Another article [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) discusses how to load more individual fragments on larger devices (where they fit) and loading a new Activity for the fragments that don't fit on smaller devices. I don't know the specifics of your layout but you might want to break the ImageViews out into fragments for phone's like your co-worker's.